# Using Rails 6 `insert_all` to import from CSV file into model which throws NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my solution trying to import data from CSV and I tried to optimise the code using `insert_all` but it is throwing NoMethodError

**user model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :role_users, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'RoleUser', dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :roles, through: :role_users, source: :role, class_name: 'Role'
end
```

**role model**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :role_users, class_name: 'RoleUser', dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :users, through: :role_users
end
```

**role user model**

```
class RoleUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role, class_name: 'Role', optional: true
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', optional: true
end
```

**using create method to persist data from csv into the database**. This works fine but not optimal for a huge data import

```
def call                                                  
  users = valid_rows.map do |row|                         
    User.create(                                          
      roles: [Role.find_or_create_by(name: row[:role])],  
      email: row[:email],                                 
      password: row[:password]                            
    )                                                     
  end   
end    

                                          
def valid_rows                                                                               
  CSV.read(file_path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol).select do |row|             
    row[:email].present? && row[:password].present? && row[:role]                            
  end                                                                                        
end
```

**BUT trying to adapt my solution to use Rails 6 `insert_all` method** and make it optimal throws NoMethodError

> NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `keys' for #Role:0x00007fe9103cd218

**What I did**

```
def call                                                            
  User.transaction do                                               
    valid_rows.map do |row|                                         
      role = Role.find_or_create_by(name: row[:role])               
      user = User.new(email: row[:email], password: row[:password]) 
      user = user.roles << role                                                        
      User.insert_all(user)                                         
    end                                                             
  end                                                               
end

def valid_rows                                                                               
  CSV.read(file_path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol).select do |row|             
    row[:email].present? && row[:password].present? && row[:role]                            
  end                                                                                        
end
```

How can I use `insert_all` for this relations I set up? Obviously I dont have it under control

Comment: This doesn't look right `user = user.roles << role`. Also the `insert_all` should probably be outside your `map`

Comment: @Eyeslandic Obviously it is. I probable need to check those Association References again on Rails Documentation page and build the necessary association to make it work. Been postponing reading the docs again